# AutoComplete Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocompletar

Como posso fazer um autocomplete do jQuery para puxar dados de um banco?

Tentei usar [este exemplo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)
só que não estou conseguindo.

Meu sistema está em ASP.NET MVC e estou utilizando o SQL Server como banco de dados.

Comment: Tentou como? Qual problema que você está tendo? Não há como adivinhar o que você precisa...

Comment: @jbueno tenho problema na hora de fazer a conexão com o meu banco de dados.

Comment: Então a tua pergunta é como fazer coneção à base de dados do servidor SQL com JavaScript, @LeonardoMacedo?

Comment: @user7393973 sim como fazer a conexão juntando com o autocomplete, eu tenho um campo no meu formulário, que ao o usuário ir digitando ele tem que ir informando os dados que ja tem no banco, da pra entender mais ou menos ?

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo, isso não é fácil nem rápido de arranjar, tens de adicionar um evento `oninput` à tua caixa de texto que use AJAX para se conectar à base de dados com PhP, verificar os dados, retomar o correto se for validado e depois ainda usar algum JavaScript para fazer o comportamento do tal auto complete. É melhor tu fazeres perguntas mais exatas em um problema de cada vez que tiveres, senão não vais ter muita sorte de alguém criar um bom exemplo de código com isso tudo a funcionar para ti. Começa por ver como é que o AJAX faz coneção do HTML/JavaScript com o PhP sem atualizar a página.

Comment: @user7393973 então, eu achei mais um exemplo https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ do jeito que esse script está ele funciona, no meu sistema, só que na parte do availableTags eu queria puxar do banco os dados, eu começei a trabalhar na area recentemente não tem muita experiencia com o javascript

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo, já tens a base de dados feita? Qual é o nome dela, da tabela e da coluna com os valores a serem retirados?

Comment: Pra esse exemplo do link na pergunta funcionar você tem que mudar search.php pra seu script em aspnet, ler a variável 'term' enviada via get e retornar um json com um array de strings(os nomes de pássaros) filtrados com o parâmetro enviado na variável term que é enviado a partir do segundo caractere digitado.

Comment: @user7393973 ja tenho sim tabela dbo.basics_Hospital é uma coluna só chamada "hospital" <- tipo string pois são nomes de hospitais

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre Obrigado Pela ajuda Antonio, vou estar fazendo o teste agora!

Answer (score 0):

Não é tão fácil, mas também não é um bicho de sete cabeças:

**Pagina onde ira o input:**

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Auto Complete - SQL</title>

            <link href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
            <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js" language="javascript"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    //Ao digitar executar essa função
                    $("#nome").focus().autocomplete("exemplo02_nomes.asp",{
                        minChars: 1 //Número mínimo de caracteres para aparecer a lista
                      , matchContains: true //Aparecer somente os que tem relação ao valor digitado
                      , scrollHeight: 220 //Altura da lista dos nomes
                      , selectFirst: true //Vim o primeiro da lista selecionado
                      , mustMatch: true //Caso não existir na lista, remover o valor
                      , delay: 0 //Tempo para aparecer a lista para 0, por padrão vem 200
                      });
                });

            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Autocomplete com Jquery em ASP - Exemplo 2</h1>
            Nome: <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Pagina onde irão as configurações do banco de dados:**

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
    <%
        ' Parametros de Conexao ao Banco
        SERVIDOR_DO_BANCO = "localhost"
        NOME_DO_BANCO = "agenda"
        USUARIO_DO_BANCO = "mateus"
        SENHA_DO_BANCO = "123456"

        ' Conexao com o Banco de dados
        Dim conexao
        Set conexao = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        conexao.Open = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={SQL Server};Server="&SERVIDOR_DO_BANCO&";Database="&NOME_DO_BANCO&";UID="&USUARIO_DO_BANCO&";PWD="&SENHA_DO_BANCO&";" 'Efetua a Conexão

        valor = Replace(Request.QueryString("q"),"'","") 'Parâmetro do campo nome, o "q" é padrão do componente autocomplete

        ' SQL de pesquisa
        sql = "SELECT codigo, nome FROM contatos where nome like '"&valor&"%' ORDER BY nome ASC"
        Set query = conexao.execute(sql)
        While Not query.eof
            ' Lista o nome
            response.write query("nome")&"|"&query("codigo")&vbCrLf
            query.movenext
        Wend
        Set query = Nothing
        Set conexao = Nothing
    %>
```

Tente ai e veja se atende as suas necessidades, adapte, mude, use como exemplo, do jeito que você achar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado Pela Ajuda Paulo, eu vou estar testando agora também

Comment: só que esse script está em VB né ?